# USB device prototype timeouts with WinUSB or HID drivers, works fine with libusb

Tags: windows, usb, winusb, libusb-win32

I'm trying to create a prototype for an USB (1.1) HID device [using an Arudino board and a CH376 module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570652/using-a-ch376-in-device-mode-it-isnt-even-detected/570986). I have managed to write the Arduino code that sets the CH376 in device mode and handles all the USB transactions.

As long as I declare the device as belonging to the "vendor specific" class, Windows 10 recognizes the device as an "Unknown device" and properly shows its VID and PID when I ask for the device details in control panel (device properties - details - hardware ids). So far so good. Then I can use [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) to assign a libusb driver to the device, which will then show under the "libusb devices" category in control panel; still all good, and I'm able to communicate with the device using the libusb functions.

**Now here comes the problem.** If I try to use WinUSB instead of libusb to manage the device, the following happens when I plug or reset the device:

1. Windows does [the usual device initialization sequence](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-usb-blog/how-does-usb-stack-enumerate-a-device/ba-p/270685): it requests the device descriptor (64 bytes), then assigns an address to the device, then requests the device descriptor again (only 18 bytes this time), then requests the configuration descriptor.
2. After five seconds Windows requests the device descriptor again. That's where the device appears in the device manager, with a "This device is working properly" status.
3. After five more seconds Windows requests the configuration descriptor again, but after retrieving just the first 8 bytes (that's the size of the control endpoint), it disconnects the device and shows it with an exclamation mark in device manager.

If I go to device properties, "general" tab, it says:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)

{Device Timeout}
The specified I/O operation on %hs was not completed before the time-out period expired.
```

And if I go to the "events" tab, the last one is "Device not started (WinUSB)" with these details:

```
Device USB\VID_1209&PID_0002\8&339ad878&0&2 had a problem starting.

Driver Name: oem168.inf
Class Guid: {88bae032-5a81-49f0-bc3d-a4ff138216d6}
Service: WinUSB
Lower Filters: 
Upper Filters: 
Problem: 0xA
Problem Status: 0xC00000B5
```

Now, if instead of declaring the device as belonging to the "vendor specific" class I declare it as a HID device and let Windows choose the proper driver, the behavior is the same, but the error message in the "general" tab is:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)

The I/O request was canceled.
```

...and the last event:

```
Device USB\VID_1209&PID_0002\8&339ad878&0&2 had a problem starting.

Driver Name: input.inf
Class Guid: {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}
Service: HidUsb
Lower Filters: 
Upper Filters: 
Problem: 0xA
Problem Status: 0xC0000120
```

I suspect that the prototype is maybe too slow for the Windows built-in USB device management libraries and libusb is more permissive, but I find this weird (the code in the Arduino board is just checking for events from the CH376 and handling them immediately in a loop) and I'm wondering if I might be doing something wrong.

Here's a dump of the trace generated by the Arduino code. The SETUP/IN/OUT events mean that the token processing has already finished; for IN tokens, any data I've written before ("Writing X bytes" logs) has been sent. By using libusb I can confirm that the data logged is indeed what I'm sending.

```
Int: USB_SUSPEND
Int: WAKE_UP
Int: WAKE_UP
Int: EP0_SETUP
  0x80 0x06 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x00 
  GET_DESCRIPTOR: DEVICE
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x12 0x01 0x10 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x09 0x12 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x02 
Int: EP0_OUT
Int: EP0_OUT
Int: EP0_OUT
Int: EP0_OUT
Int: EP0_OUT
Int: EP0_SETUP
  0x00 0x05 0x18 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
  SET_ADDRESS: 24
Int: EP0_IN
  Setting address: 24
Int: EP0_SETUP
  0x80 0x06 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x12 0x00 
  GET_DESCRIPTOR: DEVICE
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x12 0x01 0x10 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x09 0x12 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x02 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 2 bytes: 0x00 0x01 
Int: EP0_IN
Int: EP0_OUT
Int: EP0_SETUP
  0x80 0x06 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0x00 
  GET_DESCRIPTOR: CONFIGURATION
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x09 0x02 0x22 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x80 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x32 0x09 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x03 0x00 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x00 0x00 0x09 0x21 0x10 0x01 0x00 0x01 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x22 0x29 0x00 0x07 0x05 0x81 0x03 0x03 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 2 bytes: 0x00 0x0A 
Int: EP0_IN
Int: EP0_OUT
```

(5 seconds pause, no entry in device manager yet)

```
Int: EP0_SETUP
  0x80 0x06 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x12 0x00 
  GET_DESCRIPTOR: DEVICE
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x12 0x01 0x10 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x09 0x12 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x02 
Int: EP0_IN
  Writing 2 bytes: 0x00 0x01 
Int: EP0_IN
Int: EP0_OUT
```

(5 seconds pause again, the device shows in device manager as working properly)

```
Int: EP0_SETUP
  0x80 0x06 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x09 0x00 
  GET_DESCRIPTOR: CONFIGURATION
  Writing 8 bytes: 0x09 0x02 0x22 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x80 
Int: USB_SUSPEND
```

(The device shows with exclamation mark now)

By the way I get these traces by writing to the serial port, which is then read by the computer. Thinking that this might be slowing down the entire processing I tried disabling any serial port communication, and the result was the same.

**So my questions are:**

1. Am I doing something wrong? Or is Windows at fault?
2. If the later, does Windows 10 provide any way to increase the timeout for the WinUSB/HID devices processing (if that's really the issue)?

**EDIT**

If I use [Microsoft's USB hardware verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-retrieve-information-about-a-usb-device) I get the following output:

```
Event Message: USBXHCI Device Update
VendorID/ProductID: 0x1209/0x2
PortPath:  0x4, 0x4, 0x4, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0
HWVerify Errors Encountered so far:
    #1: (UsbHub3/171): Request for Language ID String Descriptor Failed
    #2: (UsbHub3/132): Device Control Transfer Error
```

...which is quite weird because the device doesn't seem to be receiving any request for a string descriptor at all!

**EDIT 2**

Per suggestion in comments I used Wireshark with USBPcap and What I see is:

- One request for the device descriptor with wLength = 18
- One request for the configuration descriptor with wLength = 9

This is consistent with the last two requests I see with my own tracing.

**EDIT 3**

In order to not make the question text growing too much [I have created a gist](https://gist.github.com/Konamiman/11af48d080c1456a9a6d9096225ed6a8) containing:

- The Arduino code I'm using.
- The detailed Wireshark capture.

And here's the schematic of the CH376 module I'm using (that's all the technical info I have found about the module):

[image]

**EDIT 4**

As suggested in comments I have modified my code so that the device now reports itself as a USB 2.0 device and provides a serial number string. Now the sequence of events from the perspective of the device is:

- Get device descriptor request (wLength = 64)
- Set address request
- Get device descriptor request (wLength = 18)
- Get configuration descriptor request (wLength = 255)
- 5 seconds pause
- Get available languages request (string descriptor 0)
- 5 seconds pause
- Get Microsoft-specific descriptor request (bRequest = 6, wValue = 0x0600) - unsupported so I stall it
- Get device descriptor request (wLength = 18)
- 5 seconds pause
- Get configuration descriptor request (wLength = 9) - response shown as USBD_STATUS_CANCELED in Wireshark

Interestingly, the Wireshark trace is exactly the same one: the languages request and the Microsoft-specific descriptor request don't show up!

The pattern seems to be that requests that are followed by the 5 second pause are invisible to Wireshark so maybe they aren't properly processed by my code and aren't considered completed by the host, but I can't see why (as I'm doing the same processing as in the second get device descriptor request, which succeeds).

Also worth noting that now I'm getting not one but six OUT token interrupts when the first device descriptor request finishes. May this be a symptom of a timing issue?

**EDIT 5**

Definitely looking like a timing issue.

I've used Zadig to set the driver for the device as libusb, then I tried to send a handful of descriptor requests in a loop; the result is that one in two requests fails, consistently. BUT if I place a 1ms delay between requests, then all of them work fine! It's as if the chip needs a "cooldown period" after a successful request. The failed requests don't appear on Wireshark or on my own logs, so it seems that the SETUP token itself is lost.

Is there any way to instruct Windows to wait a little bit between requests for a given device?

Comment: It's likely that you are focusing too much on the difference between vendor specific vs. HID and libusb vs WinUSB. Chances are your handling of the USB protocol is insufficient and it's only revealed by certain combinations as the other ones don't exercise the buggy parts immediately when the device is plugged in. Simple things can throw up USB like additional delays caused by log output. I guess you don't have a USB analyzer ready to analyze the correctness of the packets and the delay between packets.

Comment: Hi @Codo, thanks, I just wanted to include as much data as possible in the question but indeed my suspicion is that there's any problem with my code; I'm not experienced with USB device development or Windows drivers so I feel quite lost. Also the last part ("Request for string descriptor failed") puzzles me even more since I can get any string descriptor seamlessly when using libusb. As for USB analyzers: I tried a software tool (Device Monitoring Studio by HDD Software) but it's only showing the post-device setup requests (and no trace of that string descriptor request).

Comment: I'm not familiar with *Device Monitoring Studio*. The most commonly used and free tool on Windows is Wireshark with USBPcap. How do you write the log output on the Arduino? It likely slows down everything and could be the bug itself. Better remove it and use Wireshark instead. I'm not familiar with the CH376 chip or the module for it. Can you change for pull-down resistor (for host mode) to pull-up resistor (for device mode) in software. Or does it need a hardware change?

Comment: @Codo I didn't know that Wireshark was able to sniff USB traffic, that's awesome! I tried it (disabling the serial port tracing, which is something I had already tried anyway) and I see the last two requests (see updated question). As for the mode, I select host or device by sending a dedicated command to the CH376.

Comment: *"I select host or device by sending a dedicated command to the CH376"*: this does not answer whether pull-up/pull-down resistors are implemented by the CH376 and can be controlled with software, or whether additional hardware is needed on the module. And please post the detailed USB capture. There must be something wrong in the communication.

Comment: @Codo Thanks for your patience. I'm using a development module, which I assume has all the necessary components in place, connected to the digital pins of the Arduino (see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570652/using-a-ch376-in-device-mode-it-isnt-even-detected/570986). I have updated my question with the schematics of the module, and a link to a gist with my Arduino code and the detailed Wireshark trace.

Comment: Is this the entire Wireshark log? I can't see the control transfer assigning the device address. The main problem I see is that there is no response to the request for the configuration descriptor. Additional input: use protocol version 2.0 instead of 1.1 and - in particular for WinUSB - add a serial number.

Comment: @Codo I don't see any request before (and including) the SET_ADDRESS one in Wireshark, not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Anyway, I followed your suggestions for USB 2.0 and serial number and updated the question with the result

Comment: But now you said that at the device you do see "Get available languages request (string descriptor 0)".  Apparently your reply to this isn't acceptable to the driver.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-string-descriptors -- "Drivers can request the special index number of zero to determine which language IDs the device supports. For this special value, the device returns an array of language IDs rather than a Unicode string."

Comment: In my experience, a pause of 5 seconds always means that the previous request failed. So the problem is most likely with the configuration descriptor request.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for your input, I'm aware of what a request for the string descriptor 0 means and I'm returning the proper response.

Comment: @Codo Question updated with more findings, in the end it looks like a timing issue but a quite weird one and I don't know if there's something I can do about it without resorting to a custom driver.

Comment: As it seems to be a timing issue, there are basically three options (plus a combination of them): A) Writing log output causes delays. I hope you have disabled it by now. B) The CH376 chip has limitations. C) You haven't fully understood the architecture of the CH376 (if and how it queues requests, how to signal that the MCU is busy etc.) and the code thus doesn't properly interact with it.

Comment: BTW: From the way Wireshark works, it might be unable to record invalid USB transactions as the USB chip on your computer never forwards them. So it might not show the invalid SETUP request because the response was invalid or delayed and thus the USB transaction was not completed. And regarding the CH376: Do you have any good documentation for it? I've only seen the datasheet and it's seems to be insufficient to properly use the chip given the complexity of the USB protocol.

Comment: @Codo Thanks again. 1) I always test first with logs, to see what's going on, and then without, to rule out timing issues; it never makes a difference. 2) The relevant datasheets are actually the ones for the CH372, a device mode-only chip with which the CH376 is compatible: CH372DS1.PDF and CH372DS2.PDF (the later explains external firmware mode, the one I'm using) 3) What is weird is that I'm actually able to properly communicate with the chip as long as I use libusub, so I think that my code must be _mostly_ correct but of course I must be missing something.

Comment: Also at this point I don't rule out the "CH376 has limitations" option, especially since it's an old chip and it might not be prepared for modern OSes.

Answer (score 4):

I checked your code and found out that:

#define USB_REQ_SET_CONFIGURATION is 9 not 8

On a Teensy2 driving the CH376s via SPI it showed up correctly on my Mac like this:

```
         NestorDevice:

              Product ID: 0x0002
              Vendor ID: 0x1209
              Version: 1.00
              Speed: Up to 12 Mb/s
              Location ID: 0x14223000 / 48
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 100
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

I haven't tried communicating with it yet.

Also know that timing is everything. When I run your code on the Mac, relaying all the commands via serial to the Teensy, I miss certain events. The Mac is very rapidly firing off all the commands and the delay via serial is too much.

**EDIT**

There are two types of reads:

```
CMD01_RD_USB_DATA0  EQU         027H             ; / * Read the data block from the current USB interrupt endpoint buffer or the host endpoint receive buffer * /
; / * Output: length, data stream * /

CMD01_RD_USB_DATA   EQU         028H             ; / * Device mode: Read the data block from the current USB interrupt endpoint buffer and release the buffer, equivalent to CMD01_RD_USB_DATA0 + CMD00_UNLOCK_USB * /
; / * Output: length, data stream * /
```

What if we use the latter function? Would it release the buffer earlier and be ready for the next event? I'll give it a try over here to see if it makes sense.

Comment: Good catch regarding the USB_REQ_SET_CONFIGURATION  definition, thanks. I fixed it and also switched to using RD_USB_DATA for handling OUT tokens, still same results. And regarding timing, got it, but the chip is connected directly to the Arduino digital pins using parallel interface and as you can see after the logging is removed the code is pretty straightforward and to the point; so I can't figure out how I could speed up things even further.

Comment: Well I did a bit more investigation and it seems there is an issue with the synchronisation. Normally the host would wait sending new information until the client ACKs, NAKs or STALLs. Now I believe we miss certain events. I've went ahead and made some changes. I removed the STALLs in the SETUP packet routine because that's not allowed. I added explicit ACKs after the SETUP, DATA and STATUS stage. Don't have it stable yet but my gut tells me that this synchronisation is necessary. I'll let you know if I find more.

Comment: See here for more information: https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml#Control

Answer (score 1):

I've been investigating this further and found more Chinese examples on Github. What struck me was that there they add a variable amount of UNLOCK_USB commands at EP0_IN.

Once I did that I had more luck with getting a Serial device registered. Otherwise it was sitting in a loop with retries every 5secs.

So at USB_INT_EP0_IN add an extra CMD_UNLOCK_USB after processing whatever needed processing. See more [here](https://gist.github.com/S0urceror/83b3b0ce8bbe717f9c78695c932d7f1b#file-device-cpp).

Comment: Thanks for still dedicate some time to this. I've tried adding that extra UNLOCK_USB command but Windows still timeouts, however now I see that sometimes it gets to request string descriptors even when the device is USB 1.1 (previously it stopped at the configuration descriptor) so it seems like we're on the right track.

Comment: Always good to have a challenge ;-) The UNLOCK_USB works but is indeed not stable. But after some persistence I got myself a stable solution that is rock solid on MacOS, Linux and Windows (in a VM). I don't know how representative the latter is though. You'll find my final result here: https://github.com/S0urceror/ch376s-serial-device. It creates a serial device that translates everything you type to it in a terminal to uppercase.

Comment: Awesome! Could you please summarize what was the change needed/what was I doing wrong, if possible? I can't find what's it after a quick look at your code.

Comment: Quick overview of changes. Use of the read that auto unlocks, ACKs at EP0_INs to confirm the transaction is completed, a state machine to check if we're in the DATA or STATUS stage. Send EP0_OUT STALL when it's called without the previous state being SETUP or DATA. Especially the STALL sends the right signal to proceed with the interrogation at the PC. I must say this was a lucky guess. I did find a Chinese document that I translated to English that put me on this track. I'll send that to you as well.